# create a folder in the directory and save files in the new folder

Tags: python, string

I want to do the following in my program:

a) ask the user to type the name of a folder
b) create the folder in my directory
c) write files to this created folder

I've created the folder in my directory but I did not manage to write the text to a file and save it in this new folder. My strategy was to open for writing inserting the complete path of the directory + the variable that stores the name of the folder, but it did not work. Can anyone help me with that?

```
 final_text=' '.join(l)
    final_text=final_text.replace(' ,',',')
    #print('\n\n', final_text)

    def createFolder(directory):
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)
        except OSError:
            print('Error: Creating directory. '+ directory)

    user2=input('\nWrite text to a file? Type "Y" for yes or "N" for no:')

    if user2 =='Y':
        text_name=input("name your folder. E.g. './texts/': ")
        createFolder(text_name)
        out_file=open('/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/'+text_name,"w")
        out_file.write(final_text)
        out_file.close()
        print('\n\nText named',text_name, 'was written to a file. Check your directory')

    else:
        print('ok')
```

Comment: Try adding `w+` to the opening line (+ means if the file does not exist, create it) like this: `out_file=open('/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/'+text_name, "w+")`.

Comment: It did not work is useless. Please say exactly what happens, error, file in a wrong directory, no file at all on the disk, etc. But anyway, it looks that the path of the created file does not use the newly created folder, so it would be amazing that for the file to be created there...

Comment: You're trying to write content to the directory, you need to give it a filename. So `'/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/' + text_name + a_file_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first create folder, then create file within that folder:

```
import os

user_input = input('\nWrite text to a file? Type "Y" for yes or "N" for no:')
if user_input == 'Y':
    folder_name = input('name your folder. E.g. "texts": ')
    folder = os.path.join('/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/', folder_name)
    file_name = '{}.txt'.format(folder_name)
    file = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
    os.makedirs(folder)
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write('Some text')
    print('\n\nText named "{}" was written to a file. Check your directory: {}'.format(file_name, folder))
else:
    print('OK')
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library (available from Python 3.4+) makes this kind of thing a real pleasure:

```
import pathlib


new_dir_name = input('Directory name: ')
new_dir = pathlib.Path('/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/', new_dir_name)
new_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
# You have to make a file inside the new directory
new_file = new_dir / 'myfile.txt'
new_file.write_text('Hello file')
```

Comment: Yes, I had forgot to create the file inside the directory. Thanks for that!